# IIS express no funciona en mi proyecto

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Por ciertos motivos estoy usando otra máquina, en la cual tengo ahora mi proyecto ASP.NET y cuando lo compilo el navegador me dice:

> No se puede acceder a este sitio web. la página rechazó la conexión a
> localhost, Err_connection_refused.

Creé un proyecto nuevo el cual observo que el IIS EXPRESS levanta el proyecto. En cambio en el mío no. ¿Cuál podría ser el inconveniente?
Muchas gracias. Soy un principiante.

Comment: Hola @Arnaldo, asegúrate de haber ejecutado Visual Studio con privilegios de administrador. Dale clic derecho al ícono de Visual Studio y luego en "*Ejecutar como Administrador*"

Answer (score 0):

Quizás podrías verificar esta solución que a mi me funciono cuando obtuve un mensaje de error similar:

Prueba cambiando el numero del puerto en su proyecto.

Proyecto-->propiedades del proyecto-->Servidores-->Url del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu respuesta la habia visto en otra pagina cual ya la  hice y no funciono.

Comment: Bueno. Hay otras opciones que se me ocurren: 1. ¿Haz probado creándole un directorio virtual?, 2. Iniciar el VS como administrador quizás sea un tema de permisos en el IIS. ya que viene de otra maquina 3. Verificar e

Comment: probe lo que dijiste de administrador. configure para que cualquier proyecto de visual studio abra como administrador pero no m ha funcionado. no se cual es el problema. s una estupidez lo voy hacer pero no m queda otra que pasar todo mi proyecto a nuevo nuevo. de todos modos mil gracias x tu tiempo.